# How to stop Resource from showing up in curl_exec result

Tags: php

Hi I'm trying to use this script to return a value from another php script on my site without leaving the page, but I am getting the number 1 after the string (I'm assuming that the 1 is the resource number) This is the script:

```
<?php
 // create a new cURL resource
 $ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
$result = curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
 curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
 ?>

Output is somthing like this: 
"<?php include \\\\localfolder\\blabla\script.php ?>1"
```

and the 1 at the end is what I don't want showing up.

Thanks,

Robert

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option to true:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

From the [documentation](http://php.net/curl_setopt):

> **`CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`**
>   `TRUE` to return the transfer as a string of the return value of `curl_exec()` instead of outputting it out directly.